# Does TFS Proxy works with online TFS/VSTS?

Tags: tfs

i have been researching about TFS proxy, i can't find any documentation to make sure that it work or doesn't work with TFS online. our online source control are in the US and we can't move them, and our development office is overseas. TFS Proxy seems to be the best option for us to speed the development process when interacting with source control.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue with Shamrai 's answer below?

Answer (score 0):

There is experience of using proxy with vsts. You can find it here: [How to configure a TFS proxy to work with Team Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2016/10/12/how-to-configure-a-tfs-proxy-to-work-with-team-services/).

It can be applied to team foundation version control only.